# How do I check if last shutdown was clean?

Tags: shutdown, log, power-management

How can tell that my last shutdown was properly done in Ubuntu 11.10 or if the machine was powered off before shutting down the OS?

Comment: Take a look at  /var/log/syslog.0

Answer (score 25, accepted):

If the machine was shutdown properly then there must be a  shutdown log logged in `kern.log` file in `/var/log`  directory. After a shutdown whenever a normal boot occurs the OS writes the  log for the same in kern.log. Hence every boot log must be preceded by a shutdown log if the booting and shutdown process was normal.

Whenever a normal **shutdown** occurs **`"Kernel logging (proc) stopped."`** is written in kern.log.
Similarly whenever a **boot** occurs **`"imklog 5.8.1, log source = /proc/kmsg started."`** is written in kern.log

These two messages should be in the order if the shutdown was normal rather than abrupt power off. There should be no "*imklog 5.8.1, log source = /proc/kmsg started.*" message without the "*Kernel logging (proc) stopped.*" message if the previous shutdown was normal. The both message should always occur in pair in log.[image]

Just type in terminal :-

```
gedit /var/log/kern.log
```

and check for the shutdown and boot log pairs. If they are found not in pairs anywhere
that shutdown must have been abrupt.

Comment: replace gedit with your default text editor.

Comment: my kern.log is empty

Comment: @Nade try `kern.log.1`.

Comment: neither of those phrases are in my log. Not even part of them. I really need to know if my computer's being shutdown properly b/c I believe I have a kid who's simply holding down the power button.

Comment: as of Ubunutu 16.04 this seems no longer correct. i.e. I don't get `cat /var/log/syslog | grep -i "stopped"` (and similar. also sanity-tested the contrary), despite that this was clearly part of the previous shutdown messages... (the visible log stuff, when pressing ESC to kill the splash screen while shutting down) - anyone got an  update?

Comment: I can confirm the answer no longer works for recent versions of Ubuntu.

Answer (score 7):

I use the `last` command.  It lists reboots and crashes.

Comment: For this to be an answer, you need to explain how to use last.

Answer (score 3):

As of Ubuntu 16.04, a clean shutdown followed by a proper reboot will write these 2 lines one after the other in /var/log/syslog

```
Mar  9 14:14:06 *YOUR-HOSTNAME* rsyslogd: [origin software="rsyslogd" swVersion="8.16.0" x-pid="1086" x-info="http://www.rsyslog.com"] exiting on signal 15.
Mar  9 15:23:42 *YOUR-HOSTNAME* rsyslogd: [origin software="rsyslogd" swVersion="8.16.0" x-pid="1069" x-info="http://www.rsyslog.com"] start
```

Comment: This is no longer the case in Ubuntu 20.04. I don't have any mention of `rsyslogd`. Oh, and the final log entry on shutdown is `systemd[1]: Stopped QEMU KVM preparation - module, ksm, hugepages.` due to my installing `virsh` stuff on it.

Answer (score 1):

I'm running Ubuntu 22.04. I found the following was the easiest method:

`last -Fxn2 shutdown reboot`

Note that `last` shows things in reverse order, but a clean shutdown will show a shutdown followed by a boot (which will still be running):

```
reboot   system boot  5.15.0-86-generi Thu Oct 19 01:02:05 2023   still running
shutdown system down  5.15.0-84-generi Thu Oct 19 03:03:23 2023 - Thu Oct 19 03:03:30 2023  (00:00)
```

A power outage or other disorderly stop will show reboots only, with no intervening shutdowns in between them:

```
reboot   system boot  5.15.0-86-generi Thu Oct 19 01:02:05 2023   still running
reboot   system boot  5.15.0-86-generi Tues Aug 04 13:12:09 2023   still running
```

More information and other methods can be found here:

https://access.redhat.com/articles/2642741

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can run a script to check if the last shutdown was proper or not.
Just put the following lines in a bash script and run it after a system boot up.

```
#!/bin/bash
B="1"
touch data_file
echo $(($(grep -nr "$(cat  /var/log/kern.log | grep "$(date -d $(who -b | awk '{printf $3}') '+%b %-d')" | grep imklog   | grep $(cat  /var/log/kern.log | grep "$(date -d $(who -b | awk '{printf $3}') '+%b %-d')" | grep imklog | cut -d' ' -f3 | sort -k1 -r | sort --unique --stable -k2,3))" /var/log/kern.log | awk '{printf $1}' | grep -oE "[[:digit:]]{1,}")-$B))  >  data_file


if [[

($(sed -n $(cat data_file)p /var/log/kern.log | awk '{print $6}') == "Kernel") && 
($(sed -n $(cat data_file)p /var/log/kern.log | awk '{print $7}') == "logging") &&
($(sed -n $(cat data_file)p /var/log/kern.log | awk '{print $8}') == "(proc)") &&
($(sed -n $(cat data_file)p /var/log/kern.log | awk '{print $9}') == "stopped.") 


]]; then

  echo Last Shutdown-proper

else

   echo Last Shutdown_not proper 

fi

rm data_file
```

NOTE: Please be in a root user to run the script. It won't harm your system :)

Comment: I'm afraid this script now always reports an unclean shutdown with Ubuntu 20+ :-(