# Xubuntu taking a minute plus to shut down for reboot

Tags: boot, xubuntu, shutdown, reboot

This seems too long to me, and longer than I recall when I had a Mint boot. I am currently dual booting. Is this normal? If not, what might be the cause?

Comment: it takes a very long time if i reboot by the graphical method. If I go the cli and do `sudo reboot -f`, it shuts down right away. I'll forget to do this a lot, inevitably, tho. Given [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/58625/where-is-the-shutdown-log), I'm not sure there are logs I can look at to troubleshoot.

Comment: Also, I see no messages or errors during shut down. It just takes a long time, compared to other linux distros I've used and what I recall of the likes of windows 7. I've clocked the xubuntu reboot time from around 1 minute to 1:30.

Comment: Based on [this answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/108571/37165), the shut down log is found in `/var/log/kern.log` and look for `Kernel logging (proc) stopped` (This is true on my Xubuntu system also). And try pasting the message appearing before that?

Comment: Yeah, that line `Kernel logging ...` is nowhere in my logs, no matter the method of shutdown.

Comment: Try other way to get more information: Have you tried [this answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/390185)? It suggests to turn on reporting for misbehaving applications.

Comment: Don't see an error message on reboot. Nothing in logs under `/var/log` consistent with slow shutdown issue. Tried rebooting with no applications open -- same issue.

Comment: well, i mean `apport` doesn't report errors on reboot. In `/var/crash` there are recent reports for chromium and rescuetime, but there is no language related to the errors mentioned in that link, and those crashes may have been related to me troubleshooting by rebooting frequently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, this was pretty stupid, but I solved the issue. The key was to change the line `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` to `quiet` from `quiet splash` in `/etc/default/grub`, so I could see what was happening during shut down. As alluded to [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/58625/where-is-the-shutdown-log), there's not really a system log for shut downs, so removing the splash screen helps.

Anyway, I'd placed a script in `/etc/init.d` to try to manage wifi some time ago. It wasn't compliant with init script formatting, so I  gather it was taking the system some time to terminate the script. I don't know why I just recently noticed the delayed shutdown time.

Comment: I must agree that the shut down log doesn't include everything shown on screen when shutting down the machine. The most I see on my machine is `tty` process being terminated and `usb` devices being disconnected at shut down.

Answer (score 1):

Given that the question has no other clues (besides the absence of shutdown log), I can only provide the answer by guessing based on my experience only.

> Is this normal?

I can't tell, but *may be* normal for your current setup (which I don't know how you set up the dual-boot with Linux Mint). But if you were to compare with mine, yours is *not* normal.

I have a quite aged, second hand, circa-2005 single-core machine. This machine has been installed with Xubuntu 14.04 to primary partition and multiboot with other distro (always changing, but Linux Mint 17 was one of them) on other partitions.

Yet, the machine can shut down Xubuntu 14.04 in less than 10 seconds--this is my normal.

> If not, what might be the cause?

From here onwards is just guessing, talking about possibilities (which I can think of, but not necessarily have experience) for your case. You may check from the listing below.

- Did you setup shared partitions between Xubuntu and Linux Mint? Sharing partition such as `/home` may cause slow access, depending on their compatibility. However, this issue is irrelevant for sharing `/swap` partition.
- Did you setup encrypted partitions on Xubuntu? Unmounting encrypted partition may behave differently than non-encrypted ones.
- Did you setup RAID array for your Xubuntu? Occasional bug may present for systems that has been installed with RAID configuration.
- Which Xubuntu release are you using? Regular releases such as 14.10, 15.04 etc. occasionally introduce issues which are not present on LTS releases. Booting or shutdown issue could be one of them. Read the release note of your release on [this Ubuntu Wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases).
- Is the partition where Xubuntu been installed has disk error or having corrupted filesystem? You could use `fsck` to check disk error (backup first, because running `fsck` may have risk of making any corrupted filesystem even worse), or see if reinstalling Xubuntu will make any difference (as last resort).

Besides above, if Linux Mint boots and shutdown fine on the same hard disk, there is likely something amiss with your current setup for Xubuntu. That is all I can say.

**Updated**: I just found [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/26601/new-computer-hangs-on-shutdown-reboot-how-to-troubleshoot) which has similar symptoms like your case. The answer suggests "The wrong driver is loaded which prevents shutdown".

Comment: to be clear, I dual boot W7 and some ubuntu distro. It used to be Mint, now it's Xubuntu. I'll go thru some of this when I get the chance tomorrow.

Comment: None of the above apply. When I ran a live cd to perform the `fsck` command, too, I noticed that reboot was almost instantaneous. The suggested command to fix the driver in the linked page did not work for me -- the module is not found.