# Check if computer went off by crash or shutdown in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04

I would like to check if my computer with Ubuntu 14.04 was actively shutdown, or whether it crashed. I come into the office in the morning and my computer is off while it should have been on. This has happened a number of consecutive days, and I can check the computer goes off around the same time each night. So I want to know if my computer crashed or whether somebody shut it off. Is there a way to get this information from the logs?

Comment: Check `/var/log/syslog`, `last -x`

Comment: Here are a few post: [How do I check if last shutdown was clean?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/103015/how-do-i-check-if-last-shutdown-was-clean) [Where is the shutdown log?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/58625/where-is-the-shutdown-log)

Comment: Thanks. I got what I needed from the logs and `last -x ` command. It seems my computer is crashing at night.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Find in `/var/log` a `dmesg` issue, command `last` to see the exact reboot time. You will see a line starting with reboot (or may be shutdown) for all reboot/crash.
`cat /var/log/messages` from a terminal and check for messages at the time stamp of reboot or just before it. `dmesg` can give the last boot time messages.

Comment: The last command is 'last reboot', which uses a special user 'reboot' for this command.

Answer (score 1):

Issue the command

```
grep rsyslogd /var/log/syslog
```

or for less noise

```
grep -E 'rsyslogd.*(exit|start)'
```

If you see matched pairs of (blah blah)exit(blah blah) followed by (blah blah)start lines the system shutdown (at least somewhat) cleanly.  If you have two (blah blah)start lines in a row the system did not shutdown cleanly.