# When the Ubuntu laptop is turned off, the battery drains

Tags: shutdown, laptop, hp, battery

When I turn off Ubuntu, the laptop battery continues to drain. I didn't have this issue when I had Windows installed. The problem arose when I installed Ubuntu. I've tried various troubleshooting methods. The BIOS doesn't have WOL (Wake-on-LAN), which can be a problem in some cases. When I turn off the system by holding down the physical Power button on the laptop for 3 seconds, the battery charge remains unchanged.
Laptop : HP Laptop 15s-eq1320ur.

When I shut down my laptop using the terminal with the command `sudo poweroff -f` there are no battery discharge issues.
I have tried different kernel versions and different versions of Ubuntu, but the problem remains unresolved.

The problem persists when I use this button.

[image: ![enter image description here]

Comment: Thank you, sorry for my English, I corrected the question.

Comment: There is a possibility that your BIOS/UEFI support for Linux is broken/incomplete which might result in your hardware not properly translating ACPI  calls/signals or not responding to them correctly and as a result,  your system doesn’t completely shutdown so please investigate this … See for example [How do I check if last shutdown was clean?](https://askubuntu.com/q/103015)

Comment: Also, as a reference, please see this possibly related post [How to find acpi drivers for specific acpi device / Solving kernel suspend bug](https://askubuntu.com/q/1198969)

Comment: Thank you for the advice. I will try to apply it. If i try to turn off Ubuntu using GUI button, then turn it on again and immediately turn it off after the system boots, there are no issues. I suspect that it could be some processes that are not terminating correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that in the system settings you have configured that after closing the case, the laptop goes to sleep to the ram (i.e. suspend).
so maybe try this from console:

```
# echo 'deep' > /sys/power/mem_sleep
```

and if it helped, set it somewhere permanently.

or maybe check if that's the problem, do suspend from the console (without typing just given)

```
# systemctl suspend
```

watch the battery
turn on the laptop
now type the above mentioned 'deep' and do the command again and check the batteries

```
# systemctl suspend
```

turn on laptop

Comment: Thank you for the advice. I will try to apply it and will provide feedback later

Comment: if in the case of switching off from the gui or the physical button on the housing (poweroff), the problem of battery consumption DOES NOT OCCUR then look for the problem in suspend or hibernate

Comment: I tried your suggestion, but the problem persists. I have slightly revised my question, sorry for the confusion.